# appendTo() & prependTo() not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, slider

I'm running some tests with a basic slider (RoyalSlider) whereby I'm prepending/appending some of the slider content on load using the sliders event functions.

I've an issue with IE8 only, the functions simply aren't working! I've read some issues with IE8 and appendTo()/prependTo(), however, the conditions where these occur aren't similar to mine.

**jQuery**

```
(function($) {

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var homeSlider = $('#js-slider');
        if (homeSlider.length) {

            var slider = homeSlider.royalSlider({
                imageScaleMode: 'fill',
                controlNavigation: 'tabs',
                thumbs: {
                    fitInViewport: false,
                    autoCenter: false
                },
                arrowsNavAutoHide: false,
                slidesSpacing: 0,
                loop: true,
                transitionSpeed: 250,
                navigateByClick: true,
                sliderTouch: true,
                keyboardNavEnabled: true,
                addActiveClass: true,
                autoPlay: {
                    enabled: true,
                    pauseOnHover: false,
                    delay: 6000
                },
                block: {
                    moveOffset: 200,
                    speed: 600,
                    moveEffect: 'bottom',
                    delay: 600
                }
            }).data("royalSlider");

            slider.ev.on('rsAfterContentSet', function(e, slideObject) {
                homeSlider.find('.rsNav').prependTo( $('#js-slider') );
            });

            slider.ev.on('rsAfterContentSet', function(e, slideObject) {
                homeSlider.find('.rsABlock').appendTo( $('#js-homeSliderElements') );
            });
        }
    });
})( jQuery );
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container container--home">
    <div class="container slider-slideTitleWrapper" id="js-homeSliderElements"></div>
    <div class="royalSlider slider slider--home rsMinW" id="js-slider">
...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

try to use native JS methods

```
slider.ev.on('rsAfterContentSet', function(e, slideObject) {
     var parent = homeSlider.find('.rsNav');
     parent.insertBefore($('#js-slider'), parent.firstChild);
});

slider.ev.on('rsAfterContentSet', function(e, slideObject) {
     homeSlider.find('.rsABlock').appendChild($('#js-homeSliderElements'));
});
```

Comment: @SamHolguin then, problem is not in this functions

Comment: @monkeyinsight—you can't treat jQuery objects as DOM objects, you need to use something like: `parent.insertBefore($('#js-slider')[0]...)`

Answer (score 0):

Changed things around slightly and found a working method:

```
        var ready = false;

        var readyHandler = function() {
            homeSlider.find('.rsABlock').appendTo( $('#js-homeSliderElements') );
        };

        slider.ev.on('rsAfterSlideChange', readyHandler);

        slider.ev.on('rsAfterContentSet', function(e, slideObject) {
            if (!ready) {
                readyHandler();
                ready = true;
            }
        });
```